# How to plot UK towns on Google geo chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am currently constructing a geo chart for the UK in google charts, however, the UK cities are not recognised.

Is there a way to correct this?

Additionally, is it possible to plot postcodes or counties?

link to google geo charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#regions-mode-format

my code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyDlKGdxUJ8-ViDdyqV4lo6YaSHv-YTzbKU'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City',   'Case'],
    ['London',   300],
    ]);

    var options = {
      sizeAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 },
      region: 'GB',
      displayMode: 'markers',
      colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
    
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
```

`
Many thanks,

Comment: try adding option --> `resolution: 'provinces'` -- _Not supported for all countries; please test a country to see whether this option is supported._

Comment: This does not resolve this for GB